# How to use for-loop over csv file to copy files

Tags: linux, bash, file, for-loop, copy

I have a .csv file where column 8 (named filepath) contains the file location of a file I would like to copy to my home folder in Linux. Now I would like to loop over this column and use the cp function to copy the file to a folder in my home. I tried to do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read filepath
do
    for filepath in $filepath
        cp $filepath /home/files
    done
done < files.csv
```

This however does not seem to work. When I replaced the 'cp'in the for loop with an echo statement, it did not print out the file location, but the whole line of the file.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: What does your input data look like? Can you [edit] to show us a few lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a csv, then every field is separated by a comma (by default), and you can use `cut` to select the one you need.

```
cut -d, -f8 files.csv | xargs -i cp {} /home/files/
```

Comment: thanks! this worked out fine! I did not think of the cut function

Comment: If you have a version of `cp` that supports the `-t/--target-directory` switch, you can do this: `cut -d, -f8 files.csv | xargs cp -t /home/files` - the advantage of this approach being `cp` will be invoked the minimum number of times, rather than once per file.

Answer (score 2):

You can read your CSV file line by line into a BASH array and use 8th element from array:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -ra cols
do
    cp "${cols[7]}" /home/files
done < files.csv
```

If csv file is comma delimited then use:

```
while IFS=, read -ra cols
do
    cp "${cols[7]}" /home/files
done < files.csv
```

Comment: this also did the job and is a nice alternative of the right answer I chose